# DispatcherServlet - no mapping for any request. Java annotation config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning Spring and trying to run application on two different databases: H2 and Amazon AWS. For Amazon I used Manual configuration with `Tomcat`. In Deployment option I added project .war. See here: [image]
[image]

For H2 I am using annotation `@SpringBootApplication`
The problem is - when I use H2 - all works fine, but when I start Tomcat manually - get an error from Dispatcher Servlet: can't find any mapping for any requests.
Previously, before I added H2, it works well. Where do I mistake? Project Structure:

[image]

Configurations:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.socnetw.socnetw.configurations");
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

---

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.socnetw.socnetw"})
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String dbUrl;
    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public Config(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateCssResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/static/css");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".css");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateJsResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/static/js");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".js");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/js/");

    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry resolverRegistry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolverRegistry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("Lesson1");

        JpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor translationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

### }

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.socnetw</groupId>
    <artifactId>socnetw</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>socnetw</name>
    <description>Simple Social Network On Spring</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

homeController

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping({"/", "", "index.html", "index"})
    public String homePage() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/registration")
    public String getRegistrationPage() {
        return "user/registration";
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage() {
        return "user/login";
    }
```

### }

Logs:

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.21
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 4 2019 20:19:36 UTC
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.21.0
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.071 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.076 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           12.0.1+12
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\le2ta\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_socnetw_3
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\le2ta\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.21
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\le2ta\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_socnetw_3\conf\logging.properties
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\le2ta\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_socnetw_3\jmxremote.password
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\le2ta\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_socnetw_3\jmxremote.access
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\le2ta\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_socnetw_3
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.081 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\le2ta\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.21
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.081 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\le2ta\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\temp
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.081 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\jbr\\bin\server;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\le2ta\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\le2ta\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\le2ta\AppData\Roaming\npm;.]
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.205 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.226 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [319] milliseconds
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.264 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.264 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.274 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.282 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Sep-2019 10:24:06.286 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [57] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2019-09-26 10:24:06,462] Artifact socnetw:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
26-Sep-2019 10:24:15.770 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
10:24:15.779 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
10:24:15.790 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext
10:24:15.912 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - No annotated classes found for specified class/package [<NONE>]
10:24:15.951 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
10:24:16.008 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
10:24:16.012 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
10:24:16.014 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
10:24:16.017 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
10:24:16.022 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
10:24:16.032 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.ui.context.support.UiApplicationContextUtils - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@389d44df]
10:24:16.050 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
10:24:16.052 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] not found - trying original name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].
10:24:16.052 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
10:24:16.052 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].. Returning null.
10:24:16.067 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext initialized in 283 ms
10:24:16.135 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
26-Sep-2019 10:24:16.277 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\Users\le2ta\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\manager]
26-Sep-2019 10:24:16.333 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\le2ta\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\webapps\manager] has finished in [56] ms
10:24:16.698 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - ControllerAdvice beans: none
10:24:16.774 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - ControllerAdvice beans: none
10:24:16.807 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
10:24:16.807 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 672 ms
[2019-09-26 10:24:16,818] Artifact socnetw:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2019-09-26 10:24:16,818] Artifact socnetw:war: Deploy took 10,356 milliseconds
10:24:17.047 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/", parameters={}
10:24:17.051 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /
10:24:17.053 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
10:24:17.060 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/", parameters={}
10:24:17.060 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /
10:24:17.060 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
10:24:17.158 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/", parameters={}
10:24:17.158 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /
10:24:17.159 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Don't... Please don't. Both should use `@SpringBootApplication` as the only differnce is the database. For deploying a spring boot based war I suggest [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file). In short, remove your configuration and simly let your  `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. That way you will have the same config local and on AWS (as it should).